# how to search data from amazon elastic search based on multiple conditions?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

**I have pushed JSON documents like below**

```
{
"Apartment_Area": "marathahali",
 "Apartment_bhk": "2bhk",
 "Apartment_owner": "praveen",
 "Apartment_forSale": "sold_out"
}
{
 "Apartment_Area": "kadugodi",
 "Apartment_bhk": "1bhk",
 "Apartment_owner": "praveen",
 "Apartment_forSale": "for_sale"
}
```

now I am trying to search both 1bhk and 2 bhk from an elastic search using below query it gives me both 1 bhk and 2 bhk of JSON data.

/_search?pretty&q=1bhk,2bhk

Now I am trying to fetch `1 bhk` with the name `Praveen`, which mean I only want to see the data of `1 bhk` who's name is `Praveen`.

what would be the query for this any idea? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch has pretty good documentation, have a look at the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html):
Try a `POST` to `/_search?pretty` with the following body:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "Apartment_bhk" : ["1bhk", "2bhk"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That Really answered my question, Thanks :)